# Is there a full Ruby antlr4 grammar and lexer?

Tags: ruby, antlr4

I need to generate a Ruby Parser using Antlr4 
The grammar I found in https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/ruby doesn't even pretend to be complete quote
"Ruby-like language (Corundum) grammar written in ANTLR v4"

Does anyone know of a ruby grammar and lexer I can use?
Is there an inherent reason why so many grammers are available for Antlr4 and Ruby isn't - something in the language that makes it difficult to parse?

Comment: Off-topic; this is not the place to find outside resources, libraries, or software assets.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the only complete Ruby parser is the one written partially in Bison and partially in C with a hand-written lexer in C, that is part of YARV.

Even the parsers of the other Ruby implementations are either a repackaging-as-a-library of this one or a line-by-line port to e.g. Java or C# or ECMAScript. XRuby's parser was based on ANTLR, I believe, but it never had full feature parity. Ruby.NET's parser was based on the Bison grammar of MRI, which was fed to a parser generator that was specifically written to understand the Bison grammar of MRI called the Gardens Point Parser Generator. The resulting parser was then licensed to Microsoft for IronRuby.

In short: so far, nobody has been able to produce a production-quality, complete parser that is not based on the source code of YARV.

I'm not sure if the reason is necessarily that Ruby is difficult to parse, I think the problem is more that it is underspecified. There *is* the ISO Ruby Language Specification, but that was specifically written to specify only the *absolute minimal* subset of the intersection of Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9 required to write useful programs. In other words, it doesn't specify the full grammar of Ruby 1.8 or Ruby 1.9. It doesn't even specify the full grammar of the intersection of Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9. It only specifies the absolute minimum that is required to be able to write useful Ruby programs.

I do believe that the MRuby Compiler's (`mruby-compiler`) [`parse.y`](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/blob/master/mrbgems/mruby-compiler/core/parse.y) maybe independently developed, but a) it is still Bison, not ANTLR, and b) MRuby only implements a subset of ISO Ruby, IOW a subset of the subset of the intersection of Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9.